# Loop xslt template

Tags: xslt, loops

I know there are similar, more complex posts around, but I just can't get this simple thing to work.  I have a very very simple XSLT loop, which I just need to run 5 times over.  That's it.

Here's what I have:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="container">
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/myItems/data/item">
      <img src="image.gif" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine, I just need to loop this part:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/myItems/data/item">
      <img src="image.gif" />
    </xsl:for-each>
```

five times over, so that the output is literally just repeated 5 times.  I don't want to just copy and paste it five times (although that does work) as there's got to be a better way to handle it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only imperative looping construct in XSLT is `for-each` but that loops over nodes in the input document. If you don't want to implement using recursion, put the inside of the loop in a named template and then use `call-template` five times to call it.

Something like:

```
<xsl:template name='inside-loop'>
  <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/myItems/data/item">
    <img src="image.gif" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

and then where you want to call this:

```
<xsl:call-template name='inside-loop' />
```

Comment: That's what I've been trying but I just can't get my head around XSLT and nothing I've tried works.  It's got to be so simple, but I'm just missing the point somewhere along the line.

Comment: @Dan: oops, it's `call-template`, also expanded.

Comment: Thanks - so I can't put that <xsl:call-template name='inside-loop' /> into a loop - I literally just have to paste that 5 times?

Comment: @Dan: Correct (unless you want to use recursion and another template).

Answer (score 2):

Technically, XSLT is intended for *transformation* of data; looping a predetermined number of times would fall more in line with *generation* of data. The appropriate way would, unfortunately, be to copy and paste it 5 times.

Plus, you probably spent more time asking this question than it would have taken to copy and paste :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but what's the difference with using:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="container">
    <xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/myItems/data/item">
      <img src="image.gif" />
      <img src="image.gif" />
      <img src="image.gif" />
      <img src="image.gif" />
      <img src="image.gif" />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

or, better:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <div id="container">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$currentPage/myItems/data/item" mode="image"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item" mode="image">
    <img src="image.gif" />
    <img src="image.gif" />
    <img src="image.gif" />
    <img src="image.gif" />
    <img src="image.gif" />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, you can do:

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to $n">
   ....
</xsl:for-each>
```

In 1.0 you have a choice: you can use recursion (the template calls itself passing a count as a parameter, and terminates when the count drops to zero); or you can use the workaround

```
<xsl:for-each select="(//node())[position() &lt;= $n]">
```

provided there are more than $n nodes in your document.

Of course, as others have pointed out, if $n is always and forever will always be 5, you can just replicate the code 5 times.